# Using TexMaker on OS X

Tags: mac, texmaker, texinputs, environment-variables

I've started using TexMaker as an alternative to emacs (I work on both ubuntu and mac and I want to have the same programs on both) for typesetting LaTeX. TexMaker is easy to use but there is one thing that I am not managing to do: I use the environment variable TEXINPUTS and BIBINPUTS to tell latex and bibtex of the location of my private .sty files and .bib files, since I use the same ones for many documents. On the Ubuntu machine, I need to start TexMaker from commandline (and not from the mouse-click menu) for it to "see" these environment variables, on the mac I don't know how to do that, so it never sees them.

I set the variables from my .bashrc file. Perhaps that is the mistake? should it be in .login or .profile (although my .profile sources .bashrc...)?

Maybe I can add these variables directly to TexMaker, but a) I don't know how and b) I'd rather not, if possible.

This question might be more appropriate to SO, but TexMaker is such a specific piece of software that I thought to ask here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set environment variables, you need to create `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html) for details.

You should also be able to open it from the terminal using [`open(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html); this should cause it to inherent any environment variables in the usual way.